# How to send the contents of a log to a program?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, error-logging

About apache2 (httpd in CentOS) in httpd.conf directive can create custom logs like this:

```
ErrorLog "|rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/error_log_%Y-%m 1G"
```

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html

so I conclude that it is possible to send the contents of the log to a program you see is written to files, I would create a program that takes the content and store it in a database for complex future consultations, how I can do this ?

I have tried in this way without results:

```
ErrorLog "|php /etc/httpd/log2sql.php"
```

In the script I check:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('/var/log/httpd/log2sql', "\n".print_r($argv, true)."\n--------------", FILE_APPEND);
exit(0);
```

But it does not work:

```
[root@localhost httpd]# service httpd start
                                                           [FAIL]
```

And log:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /etc/httpd/log2sql.php
)

---------
```

Without arguments :(